# Perform selector when object is not nil ios

Tags: ios, null, nsobject, performselector

I habe an object `ImageURLObject`, this object have property `objectUrlImage`, when I create this object property `objectUrlImage` is nil, becourse image url has not setted yet, how can I perform selector when property has actual value? It's not a method `[self performSelector: withObject: afterDelay:]`because I don't know after what delay property become not nil..

Comment: actually what is ur question? it is not clear

Comment: the question is not understandable at all

Comment: For ex.: while (!ImageURLObject.objectUrlImage) wait in foreground as soon as ImageURLObject.objectUrlImage has value..

Comment: @LightNight Posted an answer below. You can send notification or send a message to your delegate as soon as your property value is set.

Comment: This doesn't need a perform selector to achieve this. You can either notify back when the object is not nil or just set a timer and check for the object then execute your code if found.

Comment: I would investigate whether there isn't a delegate method of some sort that is notified when the image becomes available.

Comment: You have to setup the notifier but that isn't difficult to achieve. A delegate callback would be best for when the image is set. (As Stas's updated answer recommends)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Key-Value Observing](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) (KVO) to detect a change to a property of an object.

In the setter of the `ImageURLObject` you need to perform the notification using `willChangeValueForKey` and `didChangeValueForKey`:

```
- (void)setObjectUrlImage:(NSURL *)url
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"objectUrlImage"];
    _objectUrlImage = url;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"objectUrlImage"];
}
```

and establish an observation of that property from where ever it is you want:

```
[imageUrlObject addObserver:self
                 forKeyPath:@"objectUrlImage"
                    options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                    context:NULL];
```

and observations will be notified in the following method:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context
{
    if (object == imageUrlObject && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"objectUrlImage"])
    {
        // URL changed
    }
}
```

Don't forget to remove the observation of the property in the `dealloc` method of the observer:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [imageUrlObject removeObserver:self
                        forKeyPath:@"ObjectUrlImage"];
}
```

(note that this is one of the few reasons to subclass `dealloc` in an ARC environment).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. But if I get it right, you should do what you want in setter for the property.

```
- (void)setObjectUrlImage:(UrlImage *)objectUrlImage {
    _objectUrlImage = objectUrlImage;
    // Do something here, e.g. post notification, send a message to a delegate...
}
```